# Can you minimize a Boolean expression having don't care conditions using Boolean algebraic laws?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, minimization, boolean-algebra

I have to minimise a boolean expression in SOP form having don't care conditions. I can do this by k-map but can I do this only using Boolean algebraic laws.

Q. Sigma(0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9) + d(10,11,12,13,14,15)

Comment: What is a "don't care condition"? What do you mean by minimizing? What do the functions Sigma(..) and d(..) do?

Answer (score 1):

The given lists of minterms and don't care terms can be transformed to one shorter list of implicants using Boolean laws.

The [Karnaugh-Veitch](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/) map:

[image]

From the map or by inspection of the given 14 of 16 possible terms, it is clear that there are only two terms where the expression is false: `1` and `2`.

Therefore, the expression can be written as

```
!(X0 & !X1 & !X2 & !X3) & !(!X0 & X1 & ! X2 & !X3)
```

Applying [De Morgan's theorem](https://circuitglobe.com/demorgans-theorem.html):

```
(!X0 + X1 + X2 + X3) & (X0 + !X1 + X2 + X3)
```

Both factors share `(X2 + X3)` which can thus be factored out:

```
(!X0 + X1) & (X0 + X1) + X2 + X3
```

This leads to the result:

```
!X0 & !X1 + X0 & X1 + X2 + X3
```

We implicitely set all don't care terms to `true`at the beginning. This was a good guess, but cannot be analytically derived without try-and-error.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this algebraically without knowing the actual values of ' don't care conditions' ?

Comment: Try the [Karnaugh-Veitch](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/) link in my answer. The online tool allows to experiment with different `d` values and their effect on the resulting expression.

Comment: Yes I can do that by K-map but I have been given this question to do by boolean algebraic laws